# Need driver for a DVR card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, 20.04, pci

Today, my company asked me to setup a DVR card. It's divided into two parts. First, I've to find a driver for the device, so that the OS may communicate and work with the device. Second, there should be an API (for C/C++) to communicate programmatically with the driver and use its capabilities and functionalities.

I attach pictures of the card.

[image: Behind the board]
[image: Front of the board]

AOP-4216 and AX8612-AV16N are my only clues, but I couldn't find any driver or SDK in the net. The seller didn't provide any driver. Only a CD is in the box along with the card. There's also no clue on the box. I need the driver and SDK for both Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

After installing the board on my system, lspci gives the following info about it:

```
08:01.0 Multimedia controller: Xilinx Corporation Spartan 3 Designs (Xilinx IP)
```

BYO, what should be the next step?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has reached its end of life and is not supported any more.

Comment: Google 'Xilinx Corporation Spartan 3 Designs', and can find more info.  Seems like they know about Linux, don't know how much.  Add words to search to narrow down.

Comment: @user68186: If I may have the driver source, I may make it for ubuntu 12.04. I know that 12.04 is discontinued, but because of kernel version, we need to remain in the same version of the Ubuntu.

Comment: Quick search gives results that this device is from Win 2000/XP era. Have you tested it in Windows? Xilinx is CPLD/FPGA vendor, so the device uses some special firmware inside which should be supported by the driver.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it in Windows too, but Windows 7, not XP. It searched for the driver and couldn't find it even in Windows Update. I don't know what is CPLD/FPGA.